# Dump the value of register into file

Tags: windows, assembly, x86, c++

I've reverse engineering little game on windows 32bit.

I found a string in executable which was interesting for me (it is a board game and this string represents the fact that somebody made a move on the board).

[image: Interesting memory address]

You can see that in the string is moved into `eax`. But more interesting part here is instruction before that

```
mov ebx,eax
```

Here `ebx` will contain the coordinate of a move which player made. This is what I'm interested about. I want to dump this coordinate into a file. So what I want to do is to modify assembly(in my case this code is in dll) and just write that data(which is in `ebx`) into a file.

I've done a little research but could not found anything useful. All I found is how to patch an executable like make a slightest modifications into assembly which is pretty simple. I was even wondering if there is any tool that could help me achieve this(like shift assembly code to make enough space for me to write some code in it).

One idea that I have is to write a shellcode which dumps data, then add that shellcode at the end of some section, find my string into .txt section, edit the code to jump to my shellcode and then back to original state. But that would be pretty hard because I'm not really experienced in writing shellcode.

Comment: What about setting a breakpoint there and reading `ebx` value?

Comment: I want to launch application normally without a debugger and I want it to dump the data.

Comment: Are you able to upload the executable?

Comment: No, Why do you need that?

Comment: To see what can be done. DLL would also suffice.

Comment: Do you know any methods or tools that could come handy? I would appriciate if you give me any direction.

Comment: You may try Cheat Engine. It enables you to write scripts that could dump the data you want, but if you want the DLL to do this for you, patching will be the only option.

Comment: Do you know any tools that would some useful with patching? Like automate some stuff so I don't need to do everything myself?

Comment: just an observation mov ebx,eax here ebx will contain junk ebx is being overwritten in this instruction you need the old junk value or you need what is in eax ? if you need whats in eax find where it is initialised if it is a return from some call patch the call to dump and return back

Comment: @Ojs Binary Ninja (incl. the demo version) has a shellcode compiler. You can use that to write a short C snippet to do what you want and it would emit the corresponding assembly instructions. https://scc.binary.ninja/